# IE11 issue: styles used as angularJS variable doesn't render

Tags: css, angularjs, internet-explorer-11

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" style="background:{{hex}}">
        Background-color: {{hex}}
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.hex= "#ff0000";
});
```

Here's the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2qLwoydd/

When I try to use variable as style, it works in Chrome and FF, but the background color (in the example mentioned above) doesn't apply in IE11.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ng-style` instead of style attribute with `{{}}`

**Markup**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-style="{'background-color':hex}">
    Background-color: {{hex}}
</div>
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pbz0vdv7/)